# Can someone explain this regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

```
(.*)([0-9]{6})|(.*)([0-9]{4})
```

Does it mean pick up a number that is either 6 digits or 4 digits ? Is there a concise way to write it ?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 4):

As per the expression, it matches any string with either 6 digits or 4 digits.

However since you are using a (.*) the expression will match any string with a minimum of 4 digits.

To match a **number** with 6 or 4 digits you can use:

```
/^\d{4}(\d{2})?$/
```

Answer (score 2):

the expr says:

```
(.*) take any number of arbitrary characters followed by ([0-9]{6}) six numbers
```

-OR-

```
(.*) take any number of arbitrary characters followed by ([0-9]{4}) four numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

literally: any number of characters which ends with exactly 6 numbers or exactly 4 numbers.

technically: 
The wierd thing is that the `.*` would allow anything that has any number of numbers prior to that, so anything that ends with 4 numbers or more would match?

Comment: More precisely: any number of characters with **at least** 4 digits in the end.

Answer (score 0):

1. it means any characters followed by either 6 or 4 digits
2. you think you could write it like this `(.*)(\d{4}|\d{6})` but the capturing groups would change

Answer (score 0):

I believe this means match either

an arbitrary number of any characters (`.*`) followed by a 6-digit number (`[0-9]{6}`)

or (`|`)

an arbitrary number of any characters (`.*`) followed by a 4-digit number (`[0-9]{4}`)

`.` = any character
`*` means 0, 1 or many - in this case...lookup "kleene closure"
`[0-9]` indicates a digit 0-9
`{6}` means the last pattern is repeated 6 times

now...

Wouldn't a string followed by a 6 digit number also match the pattern of a string followed by a 4 digit number?  You could add a whitespace character or end of line to the end of each pattern if this causes problems.

I may have made the assumption that what you wrote is equal to

```
((.*)([0-9]{6}))|((.*)([0-9]{4}))
```

Answer (score 0):

See other answers for what it means.

Whether or not there is a more concise way to write it, all ways would almost certainly compile to the same DFA, so be executed the same. This way is at least clear. You're having trouble understanding this one, why would you want to make it more concise?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that regex makes sense to me is if you're trying to extract a certain number of contiguous digits from a string.  If there's more than one potential match in the string, you want the last one.

The `(.*)` in the first alternative initially gobbles up the whole string, but then it backs off far enough to enable `([0-9]{6})` to capture the last six of them.  If it backs off all the way to the beginning without finding a match, the first alternative reports failure.  Control then passes to second alternative, which uses the same technique to try and the last match *four* digits.  If that fails, the overall match attempt fails.

I started to say the regex was trying to match six or four digits at the *end* of the string, because that's the usual reason why people use that technique.  But that would require it to be anchored at the end like @Cybernate's regex is.  In your case it would look like this:

```
^(?:(.*)([0-9]{6})|(.*)([0-9]{4}))$
```

The start anchor - `^` - isn't required for matching purposes, but it improves efficiency by allowing only one match attempt per alternative.  Some regex flavors are smart enough to realize that if `(.*)` doesn't match at the beginning of the string there's no point trying it at the second position, the third position, etc., but you can't count on that.

---

EDIT: I just noticed the `java` tag.  If you're using this regex with Java's `matches()` method, you don't need to add anchors; that method automatically anchors every match at both ends.  If you *don't* want your matches anchored at the end, you'll have to "pad" the regex with more dot-stars:

```
(.*)([0-9]{6}).*|(.*)([0-9]{4}).*
```